# Use JSForce to connect with a community/portal user

Tags: javascript, soap-api, soap, authentication, jsforce

it possible to connect to sales force with a community license user using jsforce?

This is what I have tried

```
let conn = new jsforce.Connection({
    loginUrl : 'https://login.salesforce.com'
});

conn.login('user@domain.com', 'mypassword', function(err, userInfo) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
});
```

This works for me when I use a full sales force user but when I use a community user I get the error:
Error: INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.

Note: I also can't login to https://login.salesforce.com with a community user so I'm wondering if there is a different loginUrl I should be using. I tried something like https://myDomain.na30.force.com/myPath but I get the same error.

I saw this post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/111782 that says

> community usernames are not globally unique, you need to use SOAP login with LoginScopeHeader

But I'm not sure how to add that with jsForce.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the login.salesforce.com host name with the full path to the community URL.

The login URL would look like below

```
https://acme.force.com/customers
```

where acme.force.com/customers is the path of the community url

Update

Seems like a bug with JSforce with community URL ,so one has to manually try doing a SOAP callout via Javascript .

Comment: I tried the full path (e.g. `https://myDomain.na30.force.com/myPath`) but I still get the same error

Comment: The community full path will not have instance like na30. From your org go to communities > Allcommunities and  fetch the url

Comment: This is what I see when I go to allCommunities https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20066539/Forum%20Links/Other/community-url.png . I tried that url but it's not working.

Comment: Did you hand construct XML without JSforce and try posting to sfdc

Comment: I haven't tried that. I don't have any experience with SOAP or SalesForce though and I'm on a tight timeline though so I don't think I have time to. I tried setting up the user agent OAuth flow and got that working though so I maybe just settle with that for now.